# how to put tag a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="function()" inside cdata

Tags: xml, google-maps, kml

i am trying put this tag a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="function()" inside tag cdata in xml but don't work

any solution??

thanks for your help

this is my code

```
<Folder>
            <name>
                <![CDATA[Cliente Demo]]>
            </name>
            <Placemark>
                <name>
                    <![CDATA[DBR132 - Geo Para el Link]]>
                </name>
                <Snippet>
                    <![CDATA[27/01/2013 12:35:09 p.m. - Vehiculo Estacionado - (Norte)]]>
                </Snippet>
                <description>
                    <![CDATA[Bogota - Britalia - Cl 163B con Kr 50 Altura:2594, Sat:4, Odom:0, Kmh: 0<div id="prueba"><br> <strong>Envio de comandos</strong><br><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="function();">UBICACION</a></div>]]>
            </description>
            <LookAt>
                <longitude>-74.0514</longitude>
                <latitude>4.7459</latitude>
                <range>8000</range>
                <tilt>55</tilt>
                <heading>359</heading>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#icon04</styleUrl>
            <Point>
                <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
                <coordinates>-74.0514,4.7459</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <styleUrl>#Norte1</styleUrl>
            <Point>
                <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
                <coordinates>-74.0514,4.7459</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
    </Folder>
```

Comment: How are you loading that KML?

Comment: from url in a server. the kml woks perfect but i cann´t load that link  i have a mistake???

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps and the Google Maps API KmlLayer will strip that out.  You need to load the KML with a third party parser like [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/)

http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/SO_KMLwJavascript.kml#prueba

(if you click on the link and look in the javascript console, you will see it attempted to run the function, but it is not defined).

[2nd example, with working "alert"](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/SO_AA-19-1a.kml)

Comment: I load my kml with api v3 google maps and this works good 
var Layer1 = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://190.143.101.59/Kml/AA-19.kml');
Layer1.setMap(map);

Comment: I can't access that link.  But KmlLayer will strip out active content from the infoWindows.

Comment: sorry try again with this file '190.143.101.59/Kml/AA-19-1.kml

Comment: [It doesn't like the \' in your KML](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/xmlProxy060215.asp?http://190.143.101.59/Kml/AA-19-1.kml), `Error: illegal character` Source Code: alert(\'Running some JavaScript!\');